# Question about limits and contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein's Complex Analysis (page 45), there is an equation:
$$\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon}^+\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}\,dz\rightarrow\int_{\pi}^0(-ii)\,d\theta=-\pi\quad\text{as }\varepsilon\rightarrow0.$$
The details are not too important, but one may take the first integral and write it as
$$\int_{\pi}^0 -ii+E(\varepsilon e^{i\theta})\cdot i\varepsilon e^{i\theta}\,d\theta,$$
where $E(\cdot)$ is bounded as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. So, the integrand depends on $\varepsilon$. I am wondering we are allowed to do this. Stein does not mention the ability to switch limit and the integral. In this case, would I have to use something like the Dominated Convergence Theorem? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You can switch the sum and the integral, and after the integration take the limit.

Comment: The absolute value inequality or, without a change of variables, the ML inequality suffices. The integrand is $c_{-1}/z + O(1)$, so the remainder is bounded, while the length of the contour tends to zero.